# Reg Ex to match numbers and commas

Tags: regex, perl

I have a .csv file and I'm only interested in rows with comma delimeted integers:

```
23,2,4,56,78,9,4,6
```

The number of comma delimited values in a row should be more than 5 (or whatever).

I'm doing this in perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\d{1,3}(,\d{3}){0,4}/
```

This will only match properly formatted comma delimited numbers (100,000,000 for instance).  It is still a terrible idea to have comma delimited numbers in a comma separated file, but I digress.  That regex is the least likely to have problems in the context.

Comment: This will not match the sample given in the OP, since subsequent groups have to be exactly 3 digits.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Somehow that seems to be what the OP wanted, I guess. Pity he didn't tell us that in his question.

Answer (score 11):

```
/^(\d+,){4,}\d+$/
```

Match a set of digits, followed by a comma. The digit-comma pair is treated as a group, which itself has to be repeated at least four times. Then you match the final number in the sequence which doesn't need to be followed by a comma.

If you don't need to capture the digits, use non-capturing groups instead (will be marginally faster):

```
/^(?:\d+,){4,}\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever:

```
/^([0-9]\+,?)\+$/
```

**Edited** to correct the error pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Will match ,,,, and will not match 10,10

Comment: Won't match, the backslash is escaping the + quantifier rendering it literal instead of a quantifier so it needs to match one digit followed by a plus sign and an optional comma followed by another plus sign. Should be: /^([0-9]+,?)+$/

Comment: And besdies it will match strings less than the desired quanity of "sets" of 5 so even when fixed as described will still not work as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d+(?:,\d+)*/
```

or including negative numbers

```
/-?\d+(?:,-?\d+)*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [0-9] instead of \d, since \d can match things that Unicode considers numbers but aren't the standard Arabic numerals.